# Pycharm debug console not working when using pytest

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

If I run a pytest test in debug mode in pycharm, once I have hit a breakpoint, I am not able to use the debug console without it raising an error.

It doesn't matter what the test is, the error is encountered regardless.

Below is the console read out and the specific error:

console read out

```
object address  : 0x2dc09d780
object refcount : 5
object type     : 0x105ccac28
object type name: ValueError
object repr     : ValueError('I/O operation on closed file.')
lost sys.stderr
```

error

```
self = <contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at 0x2dc0b4610>, typ = None
value = None, traceback = None

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        if typ is None:
            try:
>               next(self.gen)
E               ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/contextlib.py:144: ValueError
```

I am using python 3.11.5 and pytest 7.4.4.

A point of interest is that if attempted in VS code, it will work fine.

Below is an example test which will raise the error:

```py
import pytest


def example_function(a: int, b: int) -> int:

    c = a + b

    return c


class TestExample:

    def test_example(self):

        result = example_function(1,2)

        assert result == 3
```

If a breakpoint is placed at `c = a + b` and i attempt to use the console the error will occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.